# How to treat a single row of table rows: as a web element or a list of web elements (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I get rows from table with something like:

```
def get_rows_from_table(self) -> List[WebElement]:       
    table_rows = self.table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")       
    return table_rows
```

`table_rows` is a `List[WebElement]`, and a single row has many cells, so a single row itself should also be a list. Therefore, when I write something like this:

```
def get_a_specific_row_from_table(self, table_rows, row_num: int) -> List[WebElement]:            
    return table_rows[row_num - 1]
```

I got an error: `Expected type 'List[WebElement]', got 'WebElement' instead` => it is because an element from that List is defined as a WebElement.

if I want to get a cell, it should be like:

```
cell = table_row[1]
```

then this single row is a list. My question is: how should we treat a single row of table rows? as an element or a list of elements? Is it a clean way to define all table rows as `List[List[WebElement]]`

Answer (score 0):

From the (Java) [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

> Find all elements within the current context using the given
>   mechanism. When using xpath be aware that webdriver follows standard
>   conventions: a search prefixed with "//" will search the entire
>   document, not just the children of this current node. Use ".//" to
>   limit your search to the children of this WebElement. This method is
>   affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the time of
>   execution. When implicitly waiting, this method will return as soon as
>   there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an
>   empty list if the timeout is reached.

```
Specified by:
    findElements in interface SearchContext
Parameters:
    by - The locating mechanism to use
Returns:
    A list of all WebElements, or an empty list if nothing matches.
```

So, it is correct that you have a list of webelements.

For example if your html is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And you want to iterate on all the `td` for each `tr`:

```
trList= driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
print("len trList: " + str(len(trList)))
i=0
for tr in trList:
    tdList= tr.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    print("len tdList: " + str(len(tdList)))
    print ("value: " + tr.text)
    print ("-----------------"+str(i)+"------------")
    i=i+1
```

The output will be:

```
len trList: 3
-----------------
len tdList: 0
value: Month Savings
-----------------0------------
len tdList: 2
value: January $100
-----------------1------------
len tdList: 3
value: February $80 $100
-----------------2------------
```